# Is there a repository of math exercises written in latex source code available?

Tags: exam, exercises

Is there a collection of math exercises/exam questions already available for download, especially the ones that have geometric figures and pictures involving related rates and optimizations? I have been using tikz euclid to type my geometry questions but working with tikz is time consuming, and each semester I have to change the problems/figures to make my exams different. I figured that with the millions of users of latex out there someone probably had already typed a similar problem that I need, so why should I re-invent the wheel?

Comment: probably not quite what you're looking for: [AcroTeX's @EASE](http://www.acrotex.net/atease_index.php). In German there's also [SMART](http://btmdx1.mat.uni-bayreuth.de/smart/wp/)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: If it's tikz based it _should be_ at http://www.texample.net/tikz/ repository and nothing beats http://www.ctan.org/topic/exercise repository for templates even [acrotex](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/acrotex/doc/aeb_man.pdf) is present over ctan. Also Look at [Which are the advantages of TikZ over GeoGebra?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34693/15717).

Answer (score 4):

I have created a LaTeX repository with lots of images:

https://github.com/MartinThoma/LaTeX-examples/

There are no exam questions, but currently 163 TikZ examples as well es some (German) complete scripts:

- [documents/Analysis I](https://github.com/MartinThoma/LaTeX-examples/tree/master/documents/Analysis%20I)
- [documents/Analysis II](https://github.com/MartinThoma/LaTeX-examples/tree/master/documents/Analysis%20II)
- [documents/Analysis III](https://github.com/MartinThoma/LaTeX-examples/tree/master/documents/Analysis%20III)
- [documents/GeoTopo](https://github.com/MartinThoma/LaTeX-examples/tree/master/documents/GeoTopo) - I currently work on this one

Also very interesting is [TeXample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/) and [latexexamples.com](http://www.latextemplates.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Webwork uses a mix of LaTeX and Perl code: http://webwork.maa.org/moodle/

Answer (score 0):

I found some interesting geometric figures (in 2D and 3D) for exercises made with **Asymptote**  in these links:

1. [Asymptote: The Vector Graphics Language](http://www.piprime.fr/asymptote/)
2. [ASYMPTOTE un puissant langage de graphisme vectoriel](http://asy.marris.fr/asymptote/) (In
   French)
3. [Asymptote Package geometry.asy examples](http://www.piprime.fr/files/asymptote/geometry/index.html)

---

In some package manuals there are very nice examples of figures as well. For example, in the [tkz-euclide package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide), which manual is full of such beautiful geometric figures and examples of problems, that you will not notice it is in French. And the [Euclidean geometry with ASYMPTOTE (English translation).](http://www.piprime.fr/files/res/geometry_en.pdf)

Also in the [TUG Showcase page](http://www.tug.org/texshowcase/) you can find many contributions for different purposes.